# Help with adjusting the space between lines in a title

Tags: spacing, titles, alignment

I'm customizing the front page of my thesis, and I need some help adjusting the spaces between the lines of my title. The title is a little bit long, however the space between the first and second line is too small, so I'd like to add more space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.13\textwidth}
    \vspace{-0.25in}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.85\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            {\sc Pontificia Universidad Católica de Chile}\\
            {\sc Instituto de Economía}\\
            {\sc Proyecto Profesional}\\
            {\sc Magíster en Economía Aplicada}\\
            {\sc Mención Políticas Públicas}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{0pt}
\hfill
\vspace*{6cm}
\begin{center}{}
    \vspace*{2mm}
    {\Huge\bf Diseño de una evaluación de impacto para Puentes Educativos}\\
    \vspace*{4mm}
\end{center}

\vspace*{75mm}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \textbf{Profesores:} Josefa Aguirre\\
        \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, Ryan Cooper\\
        \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, Claudio Sapelli
        
    \vspace*{2mm}\\
    \textbf{Contraparte:} Fundación 99
     \vspace*{2mm}\\
    \textbf{Alumno:} Fernando Bastidas
    \vspace*{2mm}\\
    \textbf{Fecha:} 8 de diciembre de 2022
\end{tabular}


\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

And also, I'd like to center to the right, the lists of professors, I kinda did it manually, adding `\,`, so I'd really appreciate if you help me.

Comment: if you use `{\Huge` you should  include end of paragraph before the `]` or you have huge text on normal line space. Also do not use `\bf`  or `\sc` which are not defined by default in latex. Do not use `\\ `  after `\vspace` leave a bankline _before_ the `\vspace`

Comment: Can you show me on my code?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want a `figure` here, also whenever you have a size change you should include the paragraph end so you get a suitable line spacing. Here you can simply remove the `{}` group.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.13\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.90\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}%%%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.85\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            {\scshape Pontificia Universidad Católica de Chile}\\
            {\scshape Instituto de Economía}\\
            {\scshape Proyecto Profesional}\\
            {\scshape Magíster en Economía Aplicada}\\
            {\scshape Mención Políticas Públicas}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\vspace*{6cm}
\begin{center}
    \Huge\bfseries Diseño de una evaluación de impacto para Puentes Educativos

\end{center}

\vspace*{75mm}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{Profesores:} \hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Josefa Aguirre\\
Ryan Cooper\\
Claudio Sapelli
\end{tabular}\\
\textbf{Contraparte:} \hfill Fundación 99\\
    \textbf{Alumno:} \hfill Fernando Bastidas\\
    \textbf{Fecha:} \hfill 8 de diciembre de 2022
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```